Запретить этот [скрипт] и всё, что на него похоже
Вступление
Не так давно были выпилена метка скрипт (почти 200 вопросов) с её фактическими синонимом script (видимо, появилась недавно, около 20 вопросов). Также когда-то раньше существовала метка script и потенциально может быть создана метка скрипты (учитывая, сколько у нас синонимов единственного и множественного числа).
Почему данные метки не должны существовать и должны быть запрещены

Вместо конкретных меток (например javascript, php, python) вешают всякие скрипты. Из-за этого затрудняется поиск, а это для меток задача №1. Можно сделать вывод, что данные метки не просто бесполезны, а ещё и несут вред.

Так как вопросов с главной было не так уж и мало (напомню, что интернет, ныне состоящий в чёрном списке, имел примерно такое же кол-во вопросов), имелись существующие и ранее существовавшие синонимы, и высока вероятность, что её или подобную ей создадут снова, всю эту "семейку" стоит запретить (внести в чёрный список).

Внесена в так называемый Ритуал массового сожжения,то есть эта идея не новая.


Всплывающая подсказка о запрете
Если метка запрещается, то у неё высвечивается подсказка, почему она была запрещена. Сначала просто факт запрета, он для всех меток един:

Метка [название-метки] запрещена.

А потом уже конкретное предупреждение для конкретной метки. Для нашего случая я предлагаю такое:

Метка [скрипт] и её синонимы [script], [scripts] и [скрипты] неоднозначны. Используйте метки, которые обозначают конкретные языки программирование и технологии, например [javascript], [php], [python], [vbscript] и другие.

На что я ещё хотел бы обратить внимание
Нужно запретить всю эту "семейку": не только скрипт, но и scripts, и script, и скрипты. Не запретим одно, создадут другое.

Устал я уже метать бисер ... по поводу пользы мета-меток
